# Is it possible to access an external hardware device using firebase?

Tags: iphone, firebase, core-bluetooth, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I am working on an iPhone application where app has to handle an external device remotely using core Bluetooth framework. So once the app gets the information from the external device, it has to store that info in Firebase database. Till this part it is very clear.

Now the problem here is I need to connect the external hardware device to Firebase database so that firebase can access the device and send that updated information received from hardware to iPhone app.

I have gone through this https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/ document of Firebase. I have not found any way to connect an external device to Firebase. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You receive the data from the Bluetooth peripheral and you write it to the firebase database. There isn't anything in the firebase SDK to do this. This is the code you will need to write.

Comment: @Paulw11 This can be done using the script from the hardware side itself. I found the the following link which explains this. https://rominirani.com/firebase-iot-tutorial-46203a92f869#.upiezei51

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want the device to access Firebase directly, what does the iOS app have to do with things? If the iOS app is a companion app for the device, the app is the one connecting to the database, so the docs you found should contain all you need.

Comment: This case comes into frame only when the iOS app is not able to reach the hardware device. For example, if I am  outside and the hardware device is at home and then in that case I cann't access the device using Core Bluetooth right. So, let the hardware sync with firebase and then firebase will notify the app about the status of the hardware. That's the case.

Comment: So, it seems what you are actually asking is how you can integrate with firebase from an embedded device; you can't do this directly since the firebase API is too complex. The link you posted used a serial connection to a PC that connected to Firebase (you could probably use a Raspberry Pi). If you embedded device had wifi or Ethernet it could probably post simple messages to a node.js serve running somewhere and that could then update firebase.